# Need the java program for picking records in batch of 2000 records

Tags: oracle

Actually, I have `6000` records which can be processed at the client end. Now the same has been reduced to `2000`.

My current logic is

```
ArrayList aList =getDatafromTable();  SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE TXD_ID=?
 // This brings 6000 records..

for (int i=0;i<aList.size();i++){
     //loop runs for 6000 times to connect to vendor system.}
```

Now vendor system support only `2000` records.  So need to change the above query to pick `2000` records in `3` batch and pass to the loop..

Need to the looping system for the above...

Answer (score 0):

Well the best thing would be here is to limiting the number of result returned from database using `ROWNUM` like below which will return 2K records instead of 6K.

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE TXD_ID=? AND ROWNUM <= 2000;
```

Comment: they still want all 6000 records, just in three batches

Comment: if n=6000 and batch =3
 then
loop should be 1 to 2000
               2001 to 4000
               4001 to 6000

if n=6000 and batch =2
 then
loop should be 1 to 3000
               3001 to 6000

hope this elaborates the question better

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I got tired of answering my own question. :)

```
public class batch {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  int i = 1;
  int n = 505;
  int b;
  b = n / 3;
  int r = b;
  //System.out.println("r==="+r);
  int t=1;

  for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {

   System.out.println("t=="+t);
   System.out.println("r=="+r);
     for (i = t; i <= r; i++) {
    //System.out.println("t=="+t);
    //System.out.println("r=="+r);
       System.out.println(i);
   }
   t=r+1;
   r=r+b;
  }

  i=i-1;
  if(i==n){
   System.out.println("Ignore");
  }else{
   System.out.println("i=="+i);
   System.out.println("n=="+n);

  }




 }
}
```